# Unity3D after update 2018.1.f1 to 2019 I get thousands of Exceptions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had a unity game written in 2018 1.1f1 version. I wanted to open it in 2019.1.0f2 version.

I changed Runtime scripting version in projects settings from .net 2.0 to .net 4.0 equivalent. After that when I press the play button unity gives thousands of nullReferenceExceptions and ArgumentOutOfRangeExceptions.

I deleted library, obj and temp folders, but didn't work.

I think unity does not see script files. I don't know what to do for that.

Is it because depreceated objects?

How can I solve this?

Thanks,

[image]

**Edit**:

@Colin Young

- All scripts attached to their gameObjects
- All plugins loaded. Reloaded again.
- Tried saving exiting and reopening and building in visual studio.
- I get these error after upgrading to 2019. I also upgrade visual studio from 2017 to 2019. vs 2019 has already unity game development packet.
- Visual Studio does not throw any errors, just alert for depreceated classes and methods.

@BugFinder, @LeafLayer This is the script file you mentioned. Thousands of errors actualy happens in Update method. I realize that after your comment.

```
public class LoginMenuLanguageSupporter : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject LogoutButton;
    public GameObject LoginButton;
    public GameObject UserNameHintInputField;
    public GameObject PasswordHintInputField;
    public GameObject RememberMe;
    public GameObject LoggingPanelText;
    public GameObject SloganText;
    public GameObject loadingText;

    private LocalizationSupport LocalizationSupport;
    private LanguageCode PrevLanguageCode;
    void Start()
    {
        //localization bilgileri 
        if (GameObject.Find(Settings.Localization))
            LocalizationSupport = GameObject.Find(Settings.Localization).GetComponent<LocalizationSupport>();

        PrevLanguageCode = LocalizationSupport.SelectedLanguage;
        SetLanguages();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (LocalizationSupport.SelectedLanguage.Code.Equals(PrevLanguageCode.Code))
            return;

        PrevLanguageCode = LocalizationSupport.SelectedLanguage;
        SetLanguages();
    }

    void SetLanguages()
    {
        SetLanguage(ref LogoutButton, "exit");
        SetLanguage(ref LoginButton, "login");
        SetLanguage(ref UserNameHintInputField, "username");
        SetLanguage(ref PasswordHintInputField, "password");
        SetLanguage(ref RememberMe, "rememberme");
        SetLanguage(ref LoggingPanelText, "loggingon");
        SetLanguage(ref SloganText, "slogan");
        SetLanguage(ref loadingText, "loggingon");
    }

    void SetLanguage(ref GameObject go, string code)
    {
        go.GetComponent<Text>().text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(LocalizationSupport.Translate(code)) ? go.GetComponent<Text>().text : LocalizationSupport.Translate(code);
    }

}
```

**Edit 2:**

Yes. **PrevLanguageCode** is null.

Comment: Dont show the last ones.. you need the first.. Always fix them in order..

Comment: I scanned through errors. But all of them are same errors over and over. The project was working good on version 2018.

Comment: Well something is not initializing, and so is null.. we cant help you track that from a picture, if it is indeed all those.. what exactly is line 30 on LoginMenuLanguageSupporter.cs for example, there will only be "so much" on there,  work out what is null, and work out where it was, and why its null now

Comment: The problem is in the class
LoginMenuLanguageSupport.cs
line 30. At least post that code because right now it is impossible to help you

Comment: Are the scripts showing up in your project view? Are they attached to the game objects you expect them to be attached to? Are all your plugins loaded? Have you tried saving, exiting Unity and reopening the project (I assume you have a backup already)? Did you get these errors after upgrading to 2019 and before changing the scripting backend? Or did you make both changes at once? Have you tried to open the code editor and compiling there? I've seen this a _lot_ switching between beta/alpha versions and usually it clears up with one of those actions.

Comment: I tought it was a massive error. But I realized that it was just a single error happens in Update method after your comments. Thanks you guys. I will be able to solve it from here.